# VB.net extract specific URL using RegEx

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a working code but this extracts all the links from the site.

```
    strReg = "<a\s+href\s*=\s*""?([^"" >]+)""?>(.+)</a>"
    Dim reg As New Regex(strReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I want to modify the code to search only specific URLs. 
For example I only want to extract URL that contains /test/. 
My program should only display links that has the word /test/ in it.

Like:

```
http://www.website.com/sample/test/
http://www.website.com/test/
```

What should I change with my RegEx code? Thanks in advance.

---

Here is my updated working code:

```
Dim links As New List(Of String)()
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(WebSource)
For Each link As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    Dim att As HtmlAttribute = link.Attributes("href")

    If att.Value.Contains("/test/") Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(att.Value)
    End If
Next
```

it now displays all URLs with /test/ but I want to extract URLs from a google search result. is it possible?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use an appropriate parse, like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: i have updated my post with a working code using HtmlAgilityPack but i want to extract links from a google search result. I am confused on how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in google search result you need to find which element contains the links. for example below will select the `cite` nodes from the document.

```
For Each link As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//cite")
    If link.InnerText.Contains("/test/") Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(link.InnerText)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: but the links being displayed are not complete like:

http://www.website/test/....aa...a

they come with broken dots. I want to display the complete URL

Answer (score 1):

This following will match only those tags that have "/test/" in them.

```
strReg = "<a\s+href\s*=\s*""?([^"" >]+(/test/)[^" >]*)""?>(.+)</a>"
```